# Cloud Foundry unable to deploy grails app [UnknownHostException]

Tags: grails, groovy, cloud-foundry, vmc

I recently tried to deploy a Grails project on cloud foundry and I got the following error while executing "grails cf-push"

```
Environment set to production.....
Error Error executing script_ CfPush: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://api.cloudfoundry.com/users/username@gmail.com/tokens":api.cloudfoundry.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: api.cloudfoundry.com (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

and for "grails cf-push --stacktrace":

```
Error Error executing script_ CfPush: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: api.cloudfoundry.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: api.cloudfoundry.com (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: api.cloudfoundry.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: api.cloudfoundry.com
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:461)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.login(CloudFoundryClient.java:210)
at ClientWrapper.methodMissing(_CfCommon_groovy:536)
at _CfCommon_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_CfCommon_groovy:110)
at _CfCommon_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_CfCommon_groovy)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at CfPush$_run_closure1.doCall(CfPush:40)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.cloudfoundry.com
at grails.plugin.cloudfoundry.GrailsHttpRequestFactory$1.intercept(GrailsHttpRequestFactory.java:91)
at $java.net.HttpURLConnection$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7c6bfa30.connect(<generated>)
at grails.plugin.cloudfoundry.GrailsHttpRequest.executeInternal(GrailsHttpRequest.java:75)
at grails.plugin.cloudfoundry.GrailsHttpRequest.executeInternal(GrailsHttpRequest.java:89)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
... 30 more
```

Everything was working fine just couple of months ago but I had to stop working on the project for some time. When I came back to it I realized that it is no longer possible to deploy it in the way I always did.

I assumed that I needed to upgrade my cloud-foundry plugin so all in a day's work I upgraded the whole groovy/grails environment:

groovy 2.0.5 to 2.1.9
grails 2.1.2 to 2.3.1

along with the project itself using these instructions:
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html

Dependencies resolved themselves rather smoothly (along with the latest cloud-foundry 1.2.3 plugin). But deployment still fails with the same error.

"vmc info" tells me that "api.cloudfoundry.com" does not exist.
I'm out ideas. Was the address changed? Is there any by-the-book way to fix it or is it something else going on here?

Answer (score 1):

"api.cloudfoundry.com" is the URL for the hosted Cloud Foundry v1, which no longer exists. "cloudfoundry.com" has been replaced by http://run.pivotal.io, which is Cloud Foundry v2.

The  Cloud Foundry Grails plugin has not been updated to support CF v2 yet. You should use the "cf" CLI to interact with CF instead of the Grails plugin scripts. See http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/managing-apps/cf/index.html and http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/jvm/index.html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using cf for now. Doing this to be exact:

grails prod war ;
cf push --path target/app-name-0.1.war 

Works fine. The only issue is that it deploys whole app and all the dependencies each time which takes quite a bit time. The Cloud Foundry Grails plugin used to deploy only the changes I made since last upload.